# Tab-Complete (alphabetically) last match

Tags: bash, tab-completion, tcsh

We have a setup where jobs are dispatched and their results stored in directories with the same name but different trailing time stamp; eg.:

```
result_20170111T090200
result_20170111T130500
result_20170111T130225
result_20170111T130949
```

I often need to simply tab-complete the last of those, which can be frustrating since normal compilation will, in the example above complete to `result_20170111T`, force me to check that I need to enter `1`, hit tab again which will complete to `result_20170111T130`, before I again need to figure out that `9` is the correct one. Is there a better way to do this? I'm usually using tcsh, but bash would be fine also.